# How to use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

**My Setup**

I'm trying to replicate Google Now's card interface.

I have a `UIView` which is a subview of (inside) a `UIScrollView`. Both are controlled from the same `UIViewController`. The `UIView` has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` attached to it by the `UIViewController`.

The `UIScrollView` is used to scroll up and down. The `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is used to swipe away the `UIView`.

**The Problem**

I can't scroll when I'm touching the `UIView` (the card)

**The Question**

How do I implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to enable `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)` on the card so that it'll let the `UIScrollView` scroll?

I've spent several hours trying to figure this out, and I would be incredibly thankful for help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering how to do this, here's the answer:

When you declare your class, add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` after the class it subclasses. Here's what that looks like in my case:

`class CardViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Next, you add this function to the body of the `UIViewController`:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

And finally, you do this to the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

`somePanGestureRecognizer.delegate = self`