# Why it's OK to not implement all methods of UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols

While reading materials on the net, I notice that it's common to define a view controller class to adopt `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol but just implement one of its method: `gestureRecognizer (gestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer)`. See this post ([How to use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082866/how-to-use-uigesturerecognizerdelegate)) for example.

I wonder why that works. I think all methods of a protocol should be implemented, right? I check `UIViewControl` document, it doesn't mention the class implements these methods. So, could it be that those methods are optional, or an extension is defined for the protocol to provide default implementation? I check the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol document, but there is nothing indicating either of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look the declaration of the [one of the delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624213-gesturerecognizershouldbegin), you'll see:

```
optional func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

See the word `optional`? That's where the magic lies. You can define such a method as well. You just need to mark your protocol and method as `@Objc` because `optional` is an Obj-C: thing:

```
@objc protocol P {
    @objc optional func f()
}

class C : P {}
```

`f` acts as if it is an `(() -> Void)?`:

```
let p: P = C()
p.f?() // this is the same "?" operator as in "something?.somethingElse"
p.f!() // crashes
let a: (() -> Void)? = p.f // works
let b: () -> Void = p.f // error, p.f must be unwrapped
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I checked all the documents I could find, but I didn't click the function declaration. I'd think the optional keyword should appear in function signagure of ```UIGestureRecognizerDelegate``` document too.

Comment: @rayx Sometimes the documentation page for the protocol will say "all methods of this protocol are optional", but apparently not for `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.